# Notification System in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, notifications

Does anyone know any good notification plugin/gem for RoR.

I need to somehow store events and display them to the user if he/she is offline OR present them to the user in a nice way if online.

This is similar to Facebook Notifications where a user is notified for new messages, comments, likes etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a gem called [Mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) which has similar functionalities.

Comment: Just my two cents but Mailboxer looks more like a person-to-person messenging, or at least that was the intention in building it. That'll handle the Facebook Messenger requirements but for handling the notifications indicating new activity that has occurred this seems like a round peg in a square hole. I'd keep looking or write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to use Mailboxer in conjunction with [PublicActivity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity)

Comment: public activity gem is for implementing activity feed but not for notification system.