# Rails Facebook-like Notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

In my Rails 3 app I have Users, Products, and Likes. If a User posts a Product, and another User Likes this Product, I want that User to get a notification that their Product was Liked.

Is there an existing gem that handles this? I've only come across Pusher but that seems to be overkill.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of gems that do that:

RailsActivity

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Rails_Activity_Feeds

PublicActivity

http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity

https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity

I have never used them (although i probably will do it tomorrow ^^) so maybe someone with more experience can give you a better insight given your requirements (or read some part of the documentation)

Comment: I've come across public_activity. I like the gem. It creates a feed of current users activity. I didn't see a way to provide the end user with a notification.

Comment: also don't know about a overkill but look at this:
https://github.com/ging/mailboxer
suggested from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806483/notification-system-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

All the gems that are mentioned above by different people is for implementing activity feed.There is lot of difference between implementing facebook news feed and facebook notification system.

For implementing notification system, I recommend you to check these links.
[Gritter](http://rubygems.org/gems/gritter)

[Link](http://www.takeofflabs.com/posts/2-Pop-Up-Notifications-in-Rails)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye ? Faye is used in the example. I'm not sure if you'd still consider it an overkill.